# Reproject shapefile in QGIS using "save as" return weird result

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, epsg

I need to reproject a shapefile from a geographic cooridante system (ESPG: 4326) to a projected coordinate system (EPSG: 54004). Obviously something went wrong but I'm not sure what.

[image]

Comment: Is there some data  the GISse community can test on? I notice some countries are missing (see parts of South Amer. and Africa) - maybe a corrupt or invalid geometry. Can you see if there are any topology errors in the polygons?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You did nothing wrong. It's just the fact that a Mercator projection can not display the south pole.

The dataset you have contains a whole line at the bottom on 90°S, which can mathematically not be reprojected to Mercator. The points would be in inifinity.

Easy solution is to clip the Antarctic at 89°S, i.e. remove the bottom line vertices **before** reprojection. Or remove the whole Antarctic if you don't need it.